# elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by:TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)))

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Getting this error Trying to connect elasticsearch docker container with elasticsearch-python client.

```
    /home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py:379: SecurityWarning: Connecting to 'https://localhost:9200' using TLS with verify_certs=False is insecure
  **transport_kwargs,
<Elasticsearch(['https://localhost:9200'])>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_all.py", line 29, in <module>
    resp = es.index(index="test-index", id=1, document=doc)
  File "/home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py", line 404, in wrapped
    return api(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py", line 2218, in index
    __method, __path, params=__query, headers=__headers, body=__body
  File "/home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/_base.py", line 295, in perform_request
    client_meta=self._client_meta,
  File "/home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elastic_transport/_transport.py", line 334, in perform_request
    request_timeout=request_timeout,
  File "/home/raihan/dev/aims_lab/ai_receptionist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 199, in perform_request
    raise err from None
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)))
```

contents in elastic.py

```
    host = "https://localhost:9200"
es = Elasticsearch(host, ca_certs=False, verify_certs=False)
print(es)

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
resp = es.index(index="test-index", id=1, document=doc)
print(resp['result'])

resp = es.get(index="test-index", id=1)
print(resp['_source'])
```

contents in elasticsearch dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install --batch https://github.com/alexklibisz/elastiknn/releases/download/7.12.0.0/elastiknn-7.12.0.0.zip
```

urllib3==1.26.9
requests==2.27.1

Comment: Hope you are accessing the Elasticsearch url with authentication. Hence mention it with credentials url in host variable like this "https://user:pass@localhost:9200"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#disable certificate
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="https://localhost:9200", basic_auth=(USER, PASS), verify_certs=False)

#if getting an issue relevant to the certificate then:
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="https://localhost:9200", basic_auth=(USER, PASS), ca_certs=CERTIFICATE, verify_certs=False)

# I hope you know where to find certificate, e.g:
$ find /usr/share/elasticsearch -name "certs.pem"
```

**Reference**
[Follow for more](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/python-ssl-error/189407)

Comment: Can you explain why it should make a difference to add `ca_certs=` with the `verify_certs=False` already present? On my end it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 9):

you should will "https" change "http" ,this is answer

Comment: Recent versions of official elasticsearch docker image force the use of https. Changing to http results in ConnectionError

Answer (score 4):

You must check if the `scheme` is correctly set, i.e. if `https` is written instead of `http` for localhost where elastic is running on latter, then this error is produced.

The code below raises a TLS error if elastic is running only on `http`:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port':9200, 'scheme':'https'}])
```

The correct way to fix this should be to reconfigure TLS to listen at both `https` as well as `http` or to simply use the correct scheme name on which the elastic node is currently running.

The correction code should be:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port':9200, 'scheme':'http'}])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting to elasticsearch.

```
    connection_params["verify_certs"] = False
    es_client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
        **connection_params,
        headers={"user-agent": ElasticsearchStore.get_user_agent()},
    )
```