# How to fix "([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain" connecting to Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I tried in different ways, but all failed:

```py
ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}],
                   scheme="https",
                   # to ensure that it does not use the default value `True`
                   verify_certs=False,
                   ssl_context=ssl_context,
                   basic_auth=("elastic", "elastic"))
```

```py
es = Elasticsearch("https://127.0.0.1t:9200", ca_certs=False, basic_auth=("elastic", "elastic"))
```

```py
es = Elasticsearch("https://127.0.0.1t:9200", basic_auth=("elastic", "elastic"))
```

> "elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)))"

My environment:

- Windows 10
- elasticsearch 8.4.0
- Python 3.10
- Pycharm

Comment: If your host is using `https`, then your Elasticsearch stack _might_ have [basic security enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup.html) which means it requires your client to have the right certificates. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61961725/2745495